# Unable to echo the username from a $_SESSION to the page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
public function user_login()
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $userdata = $this->em->user_login($email, $password);
    $user_info = $this->em->does_user_exist($email, $password);
    if ($user_info->num_rows() == 1) {
        foreach ($user_info->result() as $row) {
            $data = array(    
                'id' => $row->id,      
                'username' => $row->username,
                'email' => $row->email,    
                'user_type' => $row->user_type,    
                'logged_in' => TRUE
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
        if($userdata) {
            echo 1;
        } else {
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller where I check if user can login and does user exist if they exist I get the all of the data and set the session. For some reason when I echo the the session username it wont display. What could be wrong?

Here's how I echo the session:

```
<div>
  hello<p><?php echo $this->session->userdata('username'); ?></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p><?php echo $data['username']; ?></p>
</div>
```

Is there any other way to echo a session?

Comment: i would var_dump `$this->session` or `$this->session->userdata`

Comment: What's the output? Is it just empty? Or do you get an error? Did you `$this->load->library('session');`?

Comment: i did this to check if session is set Array
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
echo "</pre>";

Comment: output is just Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1502943577
)

Comment: i autoload the session library in the config

Comment: function __construct()
 {
  parent:: __construct();
  $this->load->library('session'); 
  $this->load->model('Users', 'em');
 }

Comment: on my construct function i added the library as well

Comment: If added in autoload means . no need to add in constructor `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: @JYoThi i know that even if i remove that on my construct it still wont display so I'm doing a trial and error thing

Comment: `$this->session->set_userdata($data);` After this line `print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); exit;` and make sure that session is setting properly or not

Comment: I think i  know why because the page wont refresh when the user login im doing an ajax on my ci

Comment: you can return the usename as a response to ajax . and update the dom in ajax success . @Lestah

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** As per your comment you can return the usename as a response to ajax

```
        if($userdata) {
           echo json_encode(array('success'=>1,'username'=>$this->session->u‌​serdata('username'))‌​);
        } else {
           echo json_encode(array('success'=>0)‌​);
        }
```

**2nd :** And update the DOM in ajax success like this .

```
  success:function(response){

            if(response.success==1){
             $('#div_id').html(response.username);
           }else{
              $('#div_id').html('error');
           }
    }
```

**3rd :** And In your ajax dataType should be json

```
dataType:'json'
```

Comment: @but ineed that echo 1 to know the user is logged in succesfully

Comment: you can return json data like this `echo json_encode(array('success'=>1,'username'=>$this->session->userdata('username')));` and in success function access the value like this `console.log(response.success); console.log(response.username);` @Lestah

Comment: i see so i need to add dataType: json on my ajax and then to view it on my console i need to do console.log(response.success) console.log(response.username) il try this one

Comment: you can also take a look on my updated answer @Lestah

Comment: i got this when try the code Internal Server Error on my console let me double check

Answer (score 0):

Try to set session like this:

```
if ($qa->num_rows() > 0) {
            $resData = $qa->row();
            $userdata = array(
                'user_id' => $resData->user_id,
                'user_name' => ($resData->username),
                'parent_user_id' => ($resData->parent_user_id),
                'email_id' => ($resData->email_id),
                'per_page' => '20'
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
            return true;
        }
```